Miro Board Analytics: Numbers and trend of page view
We are using Miro board as a digital news paper, and we would like to get analytics of the board such as numbers and trend of weekly page view, just like Google Analytics Page view (see screenshot).

Apparently such functionality is not supported by Miro, so I am looking for a workaround.
Does anyone manage to get view counts of specific Miro board?
Thank you.
I have already tried--

REST API: Looked into Miro's REST API however this one does not expose the data I need.

Google Analytics: We cannot embed tracking code for Google analytics into Miro board.

"Insight" view for Admin User of Miro: This one only provide high level statistics of entire company but not the details of specific board (if the company has 1000 boards, we get only aggregated number of views of 1000 boards)

Miro App Examples


